# Windows 10 esxi 6.0 performance

Tags: virtualization, performance, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, windows-10

I'm running an ESXi 6.0.0-2494585-standard server. On this server are ~20 virtual machines running (ubuntu/suse  linux & windows 7 & 10). The performance of all VMs is fine, except the windows 10 VMs peformance.

In windows Task Manager the disks Read/Write speed maximum was ~3,4MB/s. The active time is quite high, usually close to 100% in idle.
The result of HDTune Benchmarks is totally fine with an average of more than 100MB/s.

I found this:
https://kerpanic.wordpress.com/2015/09/26/windows-10-slow-in-vmware-try-this/

After setting the size of the virtual memory as suggested, the task managers maximum disk read/write spead is at ~10MB/s.

Still the system is incredibly slow, when i type "c" "m" "d" into search i have to wait 5 seconds until all letters are there and another 3 seconds until the result shows up.

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Additional Information:
Win10 VM has 8GB RAM, more than enough CPU speed/cores.

The Servers Hardware (Server was bought as 100% VMWare 6.0 compatible):
Board: Supermicro X9DRi-F
CPU 1* XEON E5-2620 V2
RAM: 8 * 8GB Registered 12800 
RAID Controller: MegaRaid  9271-8i with BBU Unit
RAID configuration: RAID 6 with 5 * 3TB Caviar Red (WD30EFRX)

I hope thats all information you need.

Thanks for your help,
Paul

Comment: Nobody having any idea?

Answer (score 1):

What adapter drive were you using?

I was facing similar Windows 10 disk slow problem with ESXi 6.5.0d the latest version, but I was using a single SSD, not RAID. The adapter drive was vmw_ahci. After disable vmw_ahci and remove the disk add it again, Windows 10 disk performance much better.

```
esxcli system module set --enabled=false --module=vmw_ahci
```

This solution may not suite your situation since you were using RAID. Just for your information.